# Create a dynamic Mysql Insert from an Object

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, typescript

I have a project in Typescript in which I am trying to create an Insert through the options that I send through an `object`. Right now I have two objects, one for each Insert, these Inserts are created in different tables and with different objects. I would like to know if it is possible to create a general Insert for several objects.

This is what I currently have:

```
let object1 = [
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_SE.xml', exists: 1 },
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_IN.xml', exists: 1 },
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_BR.xml', exists: 1 }
];

`INSERT INTO ${database} VALUES` + object1.map((elem: any) => 
                    `"${elem.country}", "${elem.name}", ${elem.exists})`).join(', ');

let object2 = [
    { code: 1, folder: '/ToFtp', max: 8 },
    { code: 2, folder: '/ToXml', max: 5 },
    { code: 3, folder: '/ToMail', max: 5 }
];

`INSERT INTO ${database} VALUES` + object2.map((elem: any) => 
                    `${elem.code}, "${elem.folder}", ${elem.max})`).join(', ');
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
let object1 = [
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_SE.xml', exists: 1 },
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_IN.xml', exists: 1 },
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_BR.xml', exists: 1 }
];

let object2 = [
    { code: 1, folder: '/ToFtp', max: 8 },
    { code: 2, folder: '/ToXml', max: 5 },
    { code: 3, folder: '/ToMail', max: 5 }
];

`INSERT INTO ${database} VALUES` + ${object}.map((elem: any) => 
                    `"${elem.elem1}", ... ${elem.elemN})`).join(', ');
```

Is this possible? I'm not sure this can be done.

Comment: A few additional questions: 1) Will every entry in object1 and object 2 always have the same number of entries (even when the value for a given key might be null)? 2) Do you only need a solution for exactly two arrays of objects (object1 and object2) or do you need flexibility for any number of (ie. object3, object4, object`N`)?

Comment: @dusthaines 1 - They will not always have the same number of tickets. 2 - I need it to be flexible for multiple objects, the ones I have put are only for example

Comment: are you using `mysql` package?

Comment: @AmirSaleem I am using the promise-mysql package to create the database connection

Comment: Adding the dynamic content directly into the query is risky and prone to SQL injections. I'd suggest you use escaping. If you are using mysql package you can use `connection.query({ sql: "", values: [] })` syntax

Comment: @AmirSaleem Could you give an example for the objects I have? Would the same be valid for select queries?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create methods to prepare your query and values. You can do something like this.

```
let object1 = [
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_SE.xml', exists: 1 },
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_IN.xml', exists: 1 },
    { country: 'CO', name: 'CO_BR.xml', exists: 1 }
];

function getValues<T extends Record<string, any>[]>(obj: T) {
    const values = obj.map((item) => {
        const val = Object.values(item).map((v) => v);
        return val;
    });
    return values;
}

function getColumns<T extends Record<string, any>>(obj: T) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
}

function getFilters<T extends Record<string, any>>(obj: T) {
    const constraints: string[] = [];
    const queryArray: any[] = [];
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        constraints.push(`${k} = ?`);
        queryArray.push(v);
    });
    return {
        constraints,
        queryArray
    }
}

const columns = getColumns(object1[0]);
const values = getValues(object1);

const sql = `INSERT INTO MyTable(${columns.join(", ")}) VALUES ?`;

const filters = {
    country: "CO"
};
const selectFilters = getFilters(filters);

const selectSql = `SELECT ${columns} FROM MyTable WHERE ${selectFilters.constraints.join(" AND ")}`;

console.log(columns); // [ 'country', 'name', 'exists' ]
console.log(sql); // INSERT INTO MyTable(country, name, exists) VALUES ?
console.log(values); // [ [ 'CO', 'CO_SE.xml', 1 ], [ 'CO', 'CO_IN.xml', 1 ], [ 'CO', 'CO_BR.xml', 1 ] ]

// now you can use something like this
connection.query({ sql, values });
```

Note: Make sure you sanitize your input before using these functions to avoid any damage you may create if your input is not as you are expecting it.

Comment: Ok if you get the data and it seems that the Insert works well, now I will understand the code. If I want to do a Select, how would it work if I want several arguments in the select, in the from and in the where?

Comment: Can you please write in English?

Comment: Adding a complete example

Comment: Select with Filters example added

Comment: I just checked the data collection and the data has not been entered, the Insert has not worked. The query: ``INSERT INTO MyTable (country, name, exists) VALUES [['CO', 'CO_SE.xml', 1], ['CO', 'CO_IN.xml', 1], ['CO', 'CO_BR .xml ', 1]]`` does not catch it. The following works: ``INSERT INTO MyTable (country, name, exists) VALUES ('CO', 'CO_SE.xml', 1), ('CO', 'CO_IN.xml', 1), ('CO', 'CO_BR .xml ', 1)``

Comment: Use connection.query({sql, values})

Comment: This is how I am doing it: ``const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'database'
});``  ``pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            connection.query({ sql, values })
        });``

Comment: try `connection.query(sql, values, (result) => console.log(result))`